# pgadmin / postgresql - no pg_hba.conf entry for host

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to use pgAdmin to connect to a Postgresql server hosted by Elephantsql. However, I keep getting the error `no pg_hba.conf entry for host`:

`no pg_hba.conf entry for host "173.18.54.553", user "db_user", database "db_name", SSL on FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "xxx.xx.xxx.xxx", user "hcexhbhx", database "postgres", SSL off`

After doing some research, I edited my `pg_hba.conf` file:

```
    # TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

    # "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
    local   all             all                                     trust
    # IPv4 local connections:
    host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
    host    all             all             173.66.143.244/24       md5 (new entry)
    host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5 (new entry)
    # IPv6 local connections:
    host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
    # Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
    # replication privilege.
    #local   replication     uzrrrrd                                trust
    #host    replication     uzrrrrd        127.0.0.1/32            trust
    #host    replication     uzrrrrd        ::1/128                 trust
```

And I added a line to my `postgres.conf` file:

`listen_addresses='*'`

And I restarted postgresql before attempting to connect again.
However, I'm still getting the `no pg_hba.conf entry for host` error.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 7):

You're editing the wrong `pg_hba.conf`, connect locally with `psql` and run this

```
SHOW hba_file;
```

Then from outside edit that file. Perhaps you have two versions of PostgreSQL or you built your own. Or, you're restarting the wrong PostgreSQL. Perhaps make sure you're restarting the right one by connecting, again locally over psql, and running

```
SELECT pg_reload_conf();
```

Make sure you're editing the `pg_hba.conf` on the *SERVER* you're trying to connect to and not the *CLIENT*. (per @joanolo)

Comment: For the sake of completeness: it should be pointed out that the `hba_file` lives on the *server* [probably virtual] machine, not the *client*.

Comment: @joanolo valid point.